Align pictures vertically at bottom in mosaic grid using subcaptionbox
I'm trying to align four pictures (not necessarily the same height, but close) vertically as follows, where I want the caption (b)-(d) to be aligned at the bottom. How do I achieve this using the subcaption package?
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[position=b]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering%
    \hfill%
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \subcaptionbox{CETC}{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        } \\[5ex]
        \subcaptionbox{PETC}{
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        }%
    \end{tabular}%
    \hfill%
    \subcaptionbox{STC}{
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=70mm]{example-image-b}
    }%
    \hfill%
    \subcaptionbox{Schedule}{
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=75mm]{example-image-c}
    }%
    \hfill%
    \strut%
    \caption{Various pictures aligned in a mosaic grid}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Desired:


Perhaps pass the [b] option to tabular, as in \begin{tabular}[b]{l}. You also have some line endings that need %

You were almost there.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[position=b]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
  \subcaptionbox{CETC}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
  } \\ \\
  \subcaptionbox{PETC}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
  }
\end{tabular}\hfil
\subcaptionbox{STC}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=70mm]{example-image-b}%
}\hfil
\subcaptionbox{Schedule}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=75mm]{example-image-c}%
}

\caption{Various pictures aligned in a mosaic grid}

\end{figure}

\end{document}

A bottom aligned tabular for the first column is the key.
You don't need \hfill at the beginning and end, just use \hfil in the middle.
Don't forget the % to protect the endlines: look carefully the differences.

The same output with \valign, just for information.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[position=b]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\valign{\vfil\vbox{#}\cr
  \hbox{\subcaptionbox{CETC}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
  }}\vspace{3ex}
  \hbox{\subcaptionbox{PETC}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
  }}\cr\noalign{\hfil}
  \hbox{\subcaptionbox{STC}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=70mm]{example-image-b}%
  }}\cr\noalign{\hfil}
  \hbox{\subcaptionbox{Schedule}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=75mm]{example-image-c}%
  }}\cr
}

\caption{Various pictures aligned in a mosaic grid}

\end{figure}

\end{document}


Thanks for the resolution!

Thanks to @mbert's suggestion: the only thing missing was [b], i.e.: \begin{tabular}[b]{l}
